# creating hourly intervals in R

Tags: r, parsing, time, average

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
Count       Time 
    85     00:00:00
    86     00:15:00
    87     00:30:00
    88     00:45:00
    89     01:00:00
    90     01:15:00
    91     01:30:00
```

The intervals are every 15 minutes, i would like to aggregate the times to every 60 minutes and then take the average count for each hour. Ideally, my output would be in a dataframe. Thank you

EDIT: this may be possible with just taking an average of every four rows? If anyone knows how to go about this.

Comment: @d.b I ended up extracting the `-05:00` and hope that helps with the clarity of the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(Count = 85:91, Time = c("00:00:00", "00:15:00", 
"00:30:00", "00:45:00", "01:00:00", "01:15:00", "01:30:00"), 
    hour = c("00", "00", "00", "00", "01", "01", "01")), .Names = c("Count", 
"Time", "hour"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

First extract the hour from Time and use it as grouping variable to compute mean using aggregate

```
df$hour = sapply(strsplit(df$Time,":"), function(x) x[1])
aggregate(df[,'Count'], list(df$hour), mean)
#  Group.1    x
#1      00 86.5
#2      01 90.0
```

Comment: thanks for your input. The example i used above is a very small snippet of my df. I already have a data frame named `df` with `count` and `time` columns and im not sure how to incorporate the first part of your code (`df=structure(list...`) into my code

Comment: when I run this I am getting this error : `Error in strsplit(df$Time, ":") : non-character argument` do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Amanda - `df$Time <- as.character(df$Time)` your `Time` column is a factor i'm guessing and `strsplit` needs a character string to work.